# Get the name of folder name after unzip

Tags: php, wordpress, unzip

This my code unzip file and it's working. How get the name of unzip folder name after unzip. Like zip file name is 'demo65856.zip' and unzip folder name is 'demo'.
Thanks

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

WP_Filesystem();
$destination = wp_upload_dir();
$normal_path = $path_array;
$filename = $result->theme_file_name;
$link_filename = substr($filename, 0, -4);
$destination_path = $destination['basedir'].'/theme/';
$demo_link = $destination['baseurl'].'/theme/'.$link_filename;
$unzipfile = unzip_file( $destination_path.$filename, $destination_path);

   if ( $unzipfile ) {
    echo '<h3> <a href="'.$demo_link.'">demo link has created</a></h3>';
   } else {
      echo 'There was an error unzipping the file.';       
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual, using ZipArchive...

```
<?php 
$zip = new ZipArchive; 
if ($zip->open($filename)) 
{ 
     for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
     {   
          echo 'Filename: ' . $zip->getNameIndex($i) . '<br />'; 
     } 
} 
else 
{ 
     echo 'Error reading zip-archive!'; 
} 
?>
```

So it depends on how many files are at the base level, you may just have a base directory or a list of files. You need to try it and see what you get.